# Output Buffering not Working using Meta Tags

Tags: php, html, header, meta-tags, output-buffering

I've always used `php_flag output_buffering On` so that I could `header("Location: ...")` after some html.

Now that I've added *favicons*, *apple-touch-icons* and *og/twitter* I get this error:

```
Uncaught ErrorException: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at *file name 1*_*row* in *file name 2*:*row*
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: {closure}(2, 'Cannot modify h...', '*file name 1*', *row*, Array)
#1 *file name 2*(*row*): header('Location: ./log...')
#2 {main}
thrown in <b>*file name 2*</b> on line <b>*row*</b><br />
```

Which is the error I get when you try to send an header like a cookie (in this case `header("Location: ...")`) after something has already been sent.

This seemed strange, so I did some tests. I found out that some *meta tags* cause this error even if `php_flag output_buffering` is set to `On

```
<link rel="manifest">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon">
<link rel="icon">
<link rel="shortcut icon">
<link rel="mask-icon">

<meta itemprop="name" property="og:title" name="twitter:title">
<meta itemprop="description" property="og:description" name="twitter:description">
<meta itemprop="image" property="og:image" name="twitter:image">
<meta property="og:url" name="twitter:url">

<meta property="og:site_name">
<meta property="og:type">
<meta property="og:image:width">
<meta property="og:image:height">
<meta property="og:image:type">
<meta property="og:locale">
```

If one of these tags (one is enough) is present inside the , `php_flag output_buffering` stops working.

But it's not the same with any other tags, such as `<meta property="og:see_also">` or `<meta name="thumbnail">`. I can leave them and everything works properly.

What's wrong with these tags? I obviously can't remove all them.

My server is running on a Linux Server, with PHP 7.3 and Apache Module. Ask me for additional informations

Comment: I can't replicate this, and it sounds bizarre. Please specify where and how these tags are output. Better even, create a MCVE (also to ensure this isn't in fact a side-effect from something else in your code); https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @MarkusAO [This](https://www.typed.online/profile) is one of the non-working website pages (you can check the source code)... I don't know how I could make an MCVE: these are the tags but the same error happens for every page with redirect (the tags are included everywhere)

Comment: The following gives me no errors. `<?php ob_start(); 
echo '{{ all your tags above }}}';
header('Location: http://localhost/');
ob_flush();
exit;`

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the contents of `style.inc.php`. We, of course, can't see the contents of it on that page.

Comment: @MarkusAO solved using `ob_start()` at the very top of the script... I'd be curious to know why this changes something but I think this isn't possible

Comment: @MarkusAO should I keep `php_flag output_buffering On` in *.htaccess* or is it useless now?

Comment: For some reason your output buffering flag isn't working as expected, and I have to wonder if it's a quirk in your hosting environment. OB should be entirely agnostic as far as what it buffers. If you stick a `phpinfo()` file in there, does it show '0' or '4096' for `output_buffering`, ie. is your flag actually registered?

Comment: @MarkusAO things are getting stranger: with and without `ob_start` and `output_buffering` (so even if I leave the setting as is) I always get "local value: 4096", "master value: 90000".

Comment: `ob_start` wouldn't have an impact on the `output_buffering` flag shown in `phpinfo()`. If you get "4096", that's "On", so in principle it should already be on. What do `ini_get('output_buffering')` and/or `ob_list_handlers()` show in your script? Before/after `ob_start()`?

Comment: @MarkusAO `ini_get('output_buffering')` returns 4096 with and without `output_buffering` on *.htaccess* (are 2KB enough?). While before `ob_start()` `ob_list_handlers()` returns an array containing (`"default output handler"`), and after that an array containing two identical strings (`array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(22) "default output handler"
  [1]=>
  string(22) "default output handler"
}`)